# Secedit.exe stops working after denying execution permission to AppData directory

Tags: windows-7, permissions, icacls, appdata

I'm using the following command to deny execution permission to the *AppData* directory:

```
icacls $env:userprofile\AppData /deny "*S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)(X)"
```

The problem is, that after doing this, I'm not able to use `secedit.exe` tool anymore, as it allways returns `Access is denied` error:

```
PS Z:\Ander\Temp> secedit /export /cfg testSecedit.cfg /areas USER_RIGHTS

Access is denied.

The task has completed with an error.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info.
```

I have checked `C:\Windows\security\logs\scesrv.log`, but it didn't write anything there.

I'm confused, since apparently `Secedit.exe` tool does not reside under `$env:userprofile\AppData` tree.

`Secedit.exe` starts working after reverting back the permissions using the following command:

```
icacls $env:userprofile\AppData /reset /t
```

So, my question is, why does this permission modification affect to the `Secedit.exe` tool, if it is not under the *AppData* directory? I'm using a Windows 7 Professional 32 bit system.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue or a code issue, which is why we are here. This is I changed my environment/system permissions and things are not as they were. PowerShell cannot correct this. You may have been in the PowerShell consolehost, to run icacls but that does not make a PowerShell issue. Why this is happening is a bit odd. You are going to have to dig at this persoinally, by monitoring file/ registry settings, using tools from say MS SyusInternas, filemon, remon, procexp, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I noticed that the explained undesired scenario was not happening just when I modified AppData permissions, buth with the combination of the following two conditions:

1- Deny execution permission in AppData directory to all users:

```
icacls $env:userprofile\AppData /deny "*S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)(X)"
```

2- Remove all users from `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` (*Bypass traverse checking*) right.

As it is shown [here](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_7/2013-10-01/finding/V-26475), there are some user/groups that can be granted `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` without that being a finding:

> If any accounts or groups other than the following are granted the
> “Bypass traverse checking” right, this is a finding:
>
> Administrators, Users, Local Service, Network Service

So, I granted the right as mentioned, and now `secedit.exe` works fine even that the first condition is applied, and I'm having the expected behavior.